# "Error loading Python lib" when trying to run a python script as an executable

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pyinstaller

I am hoping to turn my python3 script into a distributable application but I'm having trouble turning the script into an executable.

I've tried using

```
pyinstaller myscript.py
```

and

```
pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py
```

to create the .exe file, however both times I've tried the .exe after it has been created, it's produced this error or a very similar error:

> [4129] Error loading Python lib
> '/var/folders/c9/r16n40jd14d9x5f__gb0p3t80000gp/T/_MEIyzoWbA/Python':
> dlopen:
> dlopen(/var/folders/c9/r16n40jd14d9x5f__gb0p3t80000gp/T/_MEIyzoWbA/Python,
> 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
> /var/folders/c9/r16n40jd14d9x5f__gb0p3t80000gp/T/_MEIyzoWbA/Python:
> code signature invalid for
> '/var/folders/c9/r16n40jd14d9x5f__gb0p3t80000gp/T/_MEIyzoWbA/Python'

The script I'm trying to run doesn't involve any images but it uses selenium webdriver, I'm very new to python so I don't know if either of these things would be a problem.
I have also tried uninstalling python3.8 and installing python3.7.9 but this has not worked either.

Comment: Are you able to run the script with no problem?  If reads like the library is not there.

Comment: @jmh Yes, the script runs perfectly when I run it from terminal manually. I don't know if I was fully clear in the question but the problem occurs when running the .exe file that is produced by using the pyinstaller command.

Comment: The problem is that the code isn't signed. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms537361(v=vs.85)

Comment: @incarnadine So I need to apply for a software publishing certificate just to sign and run the .exe file on my own computer? The end goal is to be able to distribute it and for that I would clearly need a certificate but the program doesn't even work on my own device when I run it as an executable. (It works as a script run from terminal of course.) Is this definitely the issue?

Comment: I've never worked with pyinstaller on a mac, but the error clearly says `code signature invalid`. Try a bit more research, as there are stack overflow answers already on this topic.